# remove line breaks and spaces from xml file with vb

Tags: xml, vb.net, whitespace

I have looked online for a couple days on how to do this. I find small elements of code, but I seem to be missing the larger items.

I have a number of xml files that I need to edit out extra spaces within the tags (the innertext) and I need to take out the many linebreaks (or returns--not sure if I have the right term). As well, there are elements like some text where I want to keep the text, but get rid of just the tags (the text will be absorbed into the parent tag, which is why I need to get rid of spaces and returns.

```
<root>
  <element>Some text here that has line breaks. Like this: 
    item        one 
    item two
  </element> 
</root>
```

Need it to look like:

```
<root>
 <element>Some text here that has line breaks. Like this: item item two</element>
</root>
```

I found this, but I knew it wouldn't work. I know I probably need some code that reads through and replaces (like for each node etc, etc).

Here is my start:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path As String = "c:\temp\"

    Dim doc As New XmlDocument
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = False
    doc.Load(path & filenm.Text)
    'need some loop though here with a doc.replace(something???)
    doc.Save(path & filenm.Text)
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = False
End Sub
```

Any help? BTW, all the help I get here is great. I am a newbee, but have learned a lot from you and have a pretty cool app running now that makes people think I know what I am doing. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path As String = "c:\temp\"

    Dim doc As New XmlDocument
    doc.Load(path & filenm.Text)

    'loop through every text node
    For Each Node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("//text()")
        Node.Value = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Node.Value, "\s+", " ").Trim
    Next

    doc.Save(path & filenm.Text)
End Sub
```

The following code replaces all whitespaces beetween each Tag. This didn't answer the question but can maybe helpful for somebody.

```vb
'get XML content without whitespaces
Dim XmlContent As String = doc.OuterXml

'save the content
File.WriteAllText(path & filenm.Text, XmlContent)
```

Comment: It certainly got rid of all the whitespace outside the tags, but not in, so I lost the indents. It didn't get rid of the returns or LF. Is there a way to get the indents back? Thanks though! getting closer

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Can you give me an example how it looks now and how it should look?

Comment: I can't seem to get the line breaks to show up in this comment box. tried the double spaces, </br>. Can't get it to show, so hard for me to show you. So, imagine this xml:

`<root> <element>Some text here that has line breaks. Like this:  
 (line break, or on a new line) item one  (line break, or on a new line) item two  (line break, or on a new line)
</element>  
 </root>`

 I need to take out the line breaks, or new line, as when I display the innertext in my listboxes, there are un wanted spaces and line breaks.

Comment: Now I have replaced the right whitespaces ;-) I edited my previous answer.

Comment: AWESOME!!! works like a charm. If I could bug you about one more thing. I am trying to also remove some elements like <li> text </li>. I need took keep the text between, but get rid of the <li> elements. Then, I'll use your awesome code to get ride of the left over spaces and breaks. I saw something about unwrap code. Again, thanks

Comment: I thought I would try 
`For Each Node As XmlNode In doc.GetElementsByTagName("li")
            'Node.OuterXml.Remove() not sure here
        Next`

Comment: You can use `For Each Node As XmlNode In oXmlDocument.SelectNodes("//li") Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Node) Next` to remove a node. If you want to keep the text you can extract it with `Node.SelectSingleNode("text()").Value`. Observe that this can be nothing if the element contains no text.

Comment: Thank you, again. So to keep the innertext, use `node.selectsinglenode(text()).value` then remove the node. Do I have to write the singlenode(text).value back into the xml? I want the inner text of <li> added to the inner text of its parent. Sorry for the million questions

Comment: If it is not that easy, I could always open the xml file in an editor, find/replace the <li> tag with a space. Then run the app to replace the spaces.

Comment: Ah ok, if you want to write the text from `<li />` into its parent then you can do it so: With `For Each Node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("//li") Next` you loop through all `<li />` nodes in the document. Then you can write with `If(Not(Node.SelectSingleNode("text()") Is Nothing)) Then Node.ParentNode.AppendChild(Node.SelectSingleNode("text()"))` the text from the `<li />` into the parent. Concluding you delete the `<li />` node with `Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Node)`.

Comment: @mburn You seriously rock! You saved me hours of work! Thanks again for all your help. I should have put that other question in post to up you reputation!